# Why are my columns disappearing after I refresh the data?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

The table below is connected to a query. When I refresh the table below, the last two columns' data, S and T, disappear. All the cells in these two columns contain a vlookup. How can I get the vlookup to continue working after I hit refresh?

Table:
[image: Table]

I originally thought since the last two columns I added aren't part of the original query, that every time I refresh, it gets rid of everything, but I notice that column S loses its vlookup while column T keeps it:

Column S Before Refresh
[image: Column S Before Refresh]

Column S Vlookup After Refresh:
[image: First Column Vlookup After Refresh]

Column T Vlookup After Refresh:
[image: Second Column Vlookup After Refresh]

Comment: Hi and welcome to Superuser . Which columns are the last two? Refer to them by the column letter.

Comment: Hi Yisroel. Fixed :)

Comment: Can you give more details on the ***"The table below is connected to a query"***? How was that set up? The issue seems to be with column `S` not only losing the `VLOOKUP` but even losing its column name. What is column `S` looking like (when clicking in to it) before the refresh?

Comment: I edited my original post to show what column S looks like before the refresh. And I just connected it to a table in power query. Someone else created the query though. Thanks.

Comment: So to rephrase/clarify your question: "why does the power query column disappear after refresh". The problem is that this **is** related to the way the query is done and nothing with the `VLOOKUP` you do afterward, and since you're not doing the Power Query you need to bring it up with that "someone else." This might be related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59695179/add-column-that-does-not-refresh-in-powerquery-excel

Comment: Thank you, Yisroel. I think you are right that it is related to the way the query is done. A quick solution to this was adding two entirely new columns. After writing my vlookup formulas and clicking refresh, the formulas still remained. My guess is that has to do with the answer below as well. I think originally when I clicked refresh, the pre-existing query would write over the vlookup formulas. Hence, why when I added two new columns at the end, it worked. It didn't get in the way of the pre-existing query data.

Comment: What kind of data source did you cennect?

Answer (score 1):

You ARE in fact "losing" column S.

True, I'm sure, not part of the original query, but clearly now the query does actually produce a column of data that is placed overtop the current contents when refreshing the query.

So column S apparently has blank cells written overtop the pre-existing `VLOOKUP` formulas that were in it before refresh.

Now, am I just asserting that as if I did not read your question, or is it true?

Notice in the first pic, pre-refresh, column S has a header of "Destination" or possibly something longer. All good, and it has the required formulas in the cells below. However, after refresh, the latter two pics, notice column S now has a header of "Column16"... a generic name that the query has given the 16th column in it. Apparently, when someone did something that caused the query to add the 16th column, that someone did not name the column.

That last suggests someone fiddled with the query for some particular need, and most likely had no interest in keeping the change, but... screwed that part up.

So, now you have a 16 column result being written into your Table which overwrites column S, including its header. The cell contents (blanks, values, whatever is put there) are NOT able to succeed in column T's `VLOOKUP` which is not too surprising, so it errors out.

You need to examine the query and find out what is going on that gives it a 16th column. Since the data placed does not seem out of place to you in your writing above, odds are it is a column placed to the right of all the others. Then you have a couple of basic options.

Get rid of it in the query. This seems likely to be what you'll want to do as the column appears to give blanks and not some desirable output.

Or find you wish to keep it and insert a new column (a new column T with the current column T becoming column U). Place your "column S" `VLOOKUP` in the new column T and go forward.

Related to the latter is that you might do a quick fix of doing the latter step but also hiding the 16th column so all looks like it used to. Useful as a temporary fix to ease daily work while investigating the background issue.

A thought that comes to mind is possibly someone intended to accomplish what column S's formula does but inside the query, so that the output data would have it already done. Just didn't get far in doing that, or experimenting to see if they could. It might not be a bad idea either. It could be it takes a bit more than "Hmm... Power Query... interesting..." level skills, but looks easily doable. And with a slightly higher level of skill, doing the same for column T so there are no formulas needed should be doable, though maybe noticeably harder than the column S thought. But learning by doing is a useful thing and might appeal to you.

To recap though, a column 16 is definitely overwriting the pre-refresh column S and fixing that will solve the column T errors.

Comment: Hi Jeorje, 

I think you are right. When I added to two new columns just now and clicked refresh, the query did not write over them. Everything worked correctly. I appreciate your help.